# Child theme blocks post from publishing

Tags: custom-post-types, child-theme

I created a child theme to another template, which introduces custom post type with loads of custom fields and specialized functions.

Notes:

1. I did not touch anything in the custom post type logic
2. Only change, apart from usual child theme `style.css` and `functions.php` to load parent style is to introduce different logic of `search.php` to display only that custom post type in search results

However, when I load that child template, I am unable to publish a new post of that custom post type. Updating current posts work, but clicking "Publish" button does nothing. Saving draft works.

Where should I look, apart server logs (which are empty) in order to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume it's only the child-theme which encounters this error - and therefore it is probably a small error - but not seeing any errors in the logs makes it harder to determine exactly where the error is.

First of all, I would suggest you turn on your WP_DEBUG in the wp-config.php, maybe there's an error you're missing. You can find more information on the WP_DEBUG define [here](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/).

If no errors are shown, please check your console for any errors (Right click > Inspect > console tab). I'm certain there's an error either by activating WP_DEBUG or checking the console.

I have experienced this error before, and whenever I was saving a post, there was an AJAX-error occuring. I fixed this by starting over with the child-theme, as I must have forgot something.